# how to use $_FILES[] with slim

Tags: php, slim

I'm trying to take data from a form by post with slim, but the documentation does not show how to use the `$_FILES[]`, I can take the name of the file but does not move to the folder.

```
 $app->post('/publicar', function () use ($app, $db){

  $img = $_FILES['img']['name'];
  $ruta = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
  $destino = "images/".$img;
  move_uploaded_file($ruta, $destino);
});
```

Comment: Is the destination folder writable? You can use `is_writable()` to check.

Comment: check your `error_log`

Comment: I gave permissions to the folder using filezilla code 777